# How to add MX record for AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to set up AWS SES to receive emails and have it sent to my S3 bucket.  I can presently send emails but cannot receive any emails.  AWS documentation mentions  Publishing an MX Record for Amazon SES Email Receiving ([Publishing an MX Record for Amazon SES Email Receiving](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-mx-record.html?shortFooter=true)) but it doesn't actually tell you how to do this.  Please can someone advise?

I have already created a receipt rule set and created the s3 bucket with the required permissions for emails to be sent there.  I think my issue is with not knowing how to publish the MX record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to login to your domain registrar panel to control records associated to it. To find the registrar information, try the ICANN's `whois` utility https://whois.icann.org/en.

Nearly all registrar's have a FAQ section explaining how to add a recordset to the zone. For eg.:

- Gandi - https://wiki.gandi.net/en/dns/zone/mx-record
- NameCheap - https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/322/2237/how-can-i-set-up-mx-records-required-for-mail-service
- GoDaddy - https://in.godaddy.com/help/manage-dns-zone-files-680
- etc.

Comment: does the mx priority matter? according to amazon I have "successfully" set this up but still not receiving notifications via email receiving active ruleset -> SNS -> SQS.

Comment: @Selwyn http://www.sysadminworld.com/2011/what-is-the-difference-between-mx-priority-1234-and-10203040/

Comment: I see thanks, yeah I'm not sure what my problem is. I guess i'm not understanding the architecture. I have an existing zoho mail server I want to add amazon SES MX entries to apply a ruleset to a specific email account but the zoho mail server (having higher priority) MX value always picks it up before it gets to Amazon SES mail server... but in order to use email receiving in SES you have to verify an existing email account which lives on the zoho mail server... this is confusing.

Comment: @Selwyn You can't do that. The client will always report first to the highest priority MX record; even if it is bouncing off the emails. You can have SES receive emails on a different subdomain though. That is how I have currently established my services.